# Add additional plot to subplot plotly python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, plotly

I am pulling data in from a CSV, and plotting the data.  I am plotting a series of digital signals, then putting points for when they change state.
[image: Current Digital Plots]

Now I am trying to add some text markers to a couple of the plots.  Similar to this:
[image: Goal Digital Plots]

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
points = {'A':[X_SoC[8][1], Y_SoC[8][1]], 'B': [X_SoC[9][1], Y_SoC[9][1]], 'C' :[X_SoC[9][2], Y_SoC[9][2]], 
      'D' : [X_SoC[1][1], Y_SoC[1][1]], 'E': [X_SoC[10][1], Y_SoC[10][1]], 'F' :[X_SoC[10][2], Y_SoC[10][2]],
      'G' : [X_SoC[11][1], Y_SoC[11][1]], 'H': [X_SoC[10][3], Y_SoC[10][3]], 'J' :[X_SoC[9][3], Y_SoC[9][3]],
      'K' : [X_SoC[10][4], Y_SoC[10][4]], 'L': [X_SoC[8][2], Y_SoC[8][2]], 'M' :[X_SoC[7][4], Y_SoC[7][4]],
      'N' : [X_SoC[9][4], Y_SoC[9][4]], 'P': [X_SoC[7][5], Y_SoC[7][5]]}


pt_A = X_SoC[8][1]
pt_B = X_SoC[9][1]
pt_C = X_SoC[9][2]
pt_D = X_SoC[1][1]
pt_E = X_SoC[10][1]
pt_F = X_SoC[10][2]
pt_G = X_SoC[11][1]
pt_H = X_SoC[10][3]
pt_J = X_SoC[9][3]
pt_K = X_SoC[10][4]
pt_L = X_SoC[8][2]
pt_M = X_SoC[7][4]
pt_N = X_SoC[9][4]
pt_P = X_SoC[7][5]



for i in range(Num_Channels):
    trace0.append(go.Scatter(x=df_lab["Time"], y = df_lab[Headers[i+1]], mode = 'lines', name = Headers[i+1]))
    trace1.append(go.Scatter(x=X_SoC[i], y = Y_SoC[i], mode = 'markers',   = 
False))

trace1.append(go.Scatter(x = X_SoC[8][1], y = Y_SoC[8][1], mode = 
'markers+text', text = 'A', textposition = 'bottom'))

print("The label 'A' should be at ", X_SoC[8][1], " and ", Y_SoC[8][1], " of the ninth graph down")
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = Num_Channels, cols = 1,shared_xaxes = True)

for i in range(Num_Channels):
    fig.append_trace(trace0[i],i+1,1)
    fig.append_trace(trace1[i],i+1,1)

#fig.append_trace(trace2, 9, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height = 750, width = 950, title = 'Bit Timing!')
py.iplot(fig)
```

I have tried a trace2 variable, this latest approach is to append the current point plot, but it is not showing up in any way shape or form.  My goal is to try and use the dictionary so I can just loop through.

How do I add the third plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think, programmatically, it's pretty ugly.  But it does what I am looking for.  Here is where I have ended up so far:

```
points = {'A':[X_SoC[8][1], Y_SoC[8][1]], 'B': [X_SoC[9][1], Y_SoC[9][1]], 'C' :[X_SoC[9][2], Y_SoC[9][2]], 
      'D' : [X_SoC[1][1], Y_SoC[1][1]], 'E': [X_SoC[10][1], Y_SoC[10][1]], 'F' :[X_SoC[10][2], Y_SoC[10][2]],
      'G' : [X_SoC[11][1], Y_SoC[11][1]], 'H': [X_SoC[10][3], Y_SoC[10][3]], 'J' :[X_SoC[9][3], Y_SoC[9][3]],
      'K' : [X_SoC[10][4], Y_SoC[10][4]], 'L': [X_SoC[8][2], Y_SoC[8][2]], 'M' :[X_SoC[7][4], Y_SoC[7][4]],
      'N' : [X_SoC[9][4], Y_SoC[9][4]], 'P': [X_SoC[7][5], Y_SoC[7][5]]}

for i in range(Num_Channels):
    trace0.append(go.Scatter(x=df_lab["Time"], y = df_lab[Headers[i+1]], mode = 'lines', name = Headers[i+1]))
    trace1.append(go.Scatter(x=X_SoC[i], y = Y_SoC[i], mode = 'markers', showlegend = False))

traceA = go.Scatter(x = [points['A'][0]], y = [points['A'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['A'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceB = go.Scatter(x = [points['B'][0]], y = [points['B'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['B'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceC = go.Scatter(x = [points['C'][0]], y = [points['C'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['C'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceD = go.Scatter(x = [points['D'][0]], y = [points['D'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['D'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceE = go.Scatter(x = [points['E'][0]], y = [points['E'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['E'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceF = go.Scatter(x = [points['F'][0]], y = [points['F'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['F'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceG = go.Scatter(x = [points['G'][0]], y = [points['G'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['G'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceH = go.Scatter(x = [points['H'][0]], y = [points['H'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['H'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceJ = go.Scatter(x = [points['J'][0]], y = [points['J'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['J'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceK = go.Scatter(x = [points['K'][0]], y = [points['K'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['K'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceL = go.Scatter(x = [points['L'][0]], y = [points['L'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['L'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceM = go.Scatter(x = [points['M'][0]], y = [points['M'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['M'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceN = go.Scatter(x = [points['N'][0]], y = [points['N'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['N'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)
traceP = go.Scatter(x = [points['P'][0]], y = [points['P'][1]], mode = 'markers+text', text = ['P'], textposition = 'left', showlegend = False)

print(points.keys())
print("The label 'A' should be at ", points['A'][0] , " and ", points['A'][1] , " of the ninth graph down")
#print(trace1[8])
#print(trace2)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows = Num_Channels, cols = 1,shared_xaxes = True)

for i in range(Num_Channels):
    fig.append_trace(trace0[i],i+1,1)
    fig.append_trace(trace1[i],i+1,1)

fig.append_trace(traceA, 9, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceB, 10, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceC, 10, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceD, 2, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceE, 11, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceF, 11, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceG, 12, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceH, 11, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceJ, 10, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceK, 11, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceL, 9, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceM, 8, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceN, 10, 1)
fig.append_trace(traceP, 8, 1)


fig['layout'].update(height = 750, width = 950, title = 'Bit Timing!')
py.iplot(fig)
```

I am definitely open to ideas to make it better.

Thanks